# How to print out contents of file in C using function?

Tags: c, file

I'm very noob in C, and also we are not allowed to use ftell() or something similar. I can't print out the contents of my file as it is asked from me.This is eventually task in which I should've created functions that reads contents of file and store it in array then returns number of items in file, and in main() I had to print out using readStations() function. In main() also there should've been railwayLine[100] array of type station.

File has text as follows:

```
1. 0.0 London-Kings-Cross*
2. 3.9 Finsbury-Park*
...
```

First of all, I created **typedef struct** called **station** with properties **km** and **name** which are the distance and name of stations. I've tried to create function *readStations(char filename[20], station line[])*

My attempt is as follows:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 typedef struct {
   char name[30];
   double km;
 } station;

 int readStations(char filename[20], station line[]){

   FILE* openedFile;
   openedFile = fopen(filename, "r");

   if(openedFile == NULL){ 
     printf("Some problem occured with opening of file");
     return 1;
   }

   station stations;

   int count = 0;
   for (; !feof(openedFile); count++){
     fscanf(openedFile, "%lf %s", &stations.km, stations.name);
   }

   int numberOfStations = count;

   return count;
  }


  int main(){

    station railwayLine[100];
    printf("");
  }
```

Actually, it returns me the number of items of .txt file but in main I don't know how to print out all items as they look in .txt file.

Comment: Use `ftell` to get the file size, and then use `fread` to get the entire amount of data into a buffer (array of characters) which you can then print.

Comment: @goodvibration we are not allowed to use ftell() or any other similar stuff =(

Comment: @MarkDark _"we are not allowed to use ftell()...."_, that information belongs into the question.

Comment: You'd have to call `readStations()`.  You probably need a dynamically allocated array of stations (you can `malloc()` an initial array, and then `realloc()` each time you need more space (double the number of allocated stations each time you add more space).  That will be tracked via a pointer — which could perhaps be global, or could be returned instead of the number of stations read, or you could create another structure type containing a count of the number of stations read, a count of the number of structures allocated, and a pointer to the structures.  This would be how I'd do it.

Comment: Ouch!  Such limitations make life difficult — and it is crucial that such restrictions are documented so those attempting to help can do so usefully.  Of course, you're using at least 3 pointers in your `readStations()` function — both parameters are 'really' pointers, and there's a `FILE *` too.  Your `main()` function needs to be a little less minimal, I think.  It should show the call to `readStations()` (though it isn't too hard to guess what it looks like — but guessing shouldn't be necessary and many a problem has been solved by looking at the calling code rather than the called code).

Comment: Your code in the function needs to write to the `line` array that is passed into the function — at the moment, you ignore that parameter.  You can return the count of stations.  A redesigned interface would pass the maximum number of stations in the array defined in `main()` so you can avoid a [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) problem.  And you can write a function to print the values in an array of `station` entries.

Comment: Also, note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/) even when the condition is in a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Comment: Is it required to store everything before printing? If yes, that is certainly not a right way to print content of files. The best is to print each sample content as it is read. Leffler's suggestions are the best if you can't do that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is `do ... while(!feof(file))` OK?

Comment: Not really.  You also need to test the read operation and respond to it reporting EOF.  So, by the time you reach the end `while` test, you should already be aware that you’ve reached EOF, so the test is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to meet your concerns.  Note that the `readStations()` function is now told how many stations it can store.  It also closes the file that was opened.  The `printStations()` function prints the data.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[30];
    double km;
} station;

static int readStations(char filename[], int max_line, station line[])
{
    FILE *openedFile = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (openedFile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Some problem occurred opening the file %s\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < max_line; count++)
    {
        if (fscanf(openedFile, "%lf %s", &line[count].km, line[count].name) != 2)
            break;
    }

    fclose(openedFile);
    return count;
}

static void printStations(int num_stations, station line[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_stations; i++)
        printf("%2d. %6.2f km - %s\n", i, line[i].km, line[i].name);
}

int main(void)
{
    enum { MAX_STATIONS = 100 };
    station railwayLine[MAX_STATIONS];
    int num_stations = readStations("stations.txt", MAX_STATIONS, railwayLine);
    printStations(num_stations, railwayLine);
}
```

Given input data (file `stations.txt`):

```
0.0 London-Kings-Cross*
3.9 Finsbury-Park*
```

The output is:

```
 0.   0.00 km - London-Kings-Cross*
 1.   3.90 km - Finsbury-Park*
```